# Should I install Debian or Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu

I am new to free software and I want to install a Linux OS. I don't know anything about programming and I do not intend to do a professional use of my computer, just a personal, simple-user experience ---that's why I'm moving to Linux indeed.

So, which one between those two do you recommend for me? I've read some things about their philosophy and understood that Ubuntu is more commercial ("nerds becoming rich") and that Debian follows more the philosophy of free software, and that makes a good reason for me to choose Debian. I also read that Debian is more stable than Ubuntu. **But** it kind of gave me the impression that it was more difficult to install/use than Ubuntu, and I don't want my life to get more complicated. Since Ubuntu is more popular, I'm afraid it will be easier to find solutions for it.

Also, what about the **software center** of Debian and Ubuntu? Is Ubuntu's repository bigger than Debian's? I'd like to install Spotify, Adobe Photoshop and that kind of commercial apps...

Which would you recommend for a beginner in Linux who wants to keep Windows OS in a partition and to install some commercial apps?

Comment: Consider trying both? Possibly in a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with both of them and I would say that for a beginner with Linux, Ubuntu would be a better option. I think it is easier to use for the purpouses you are explaining. Debian I would say is recomended to have some background with Linux. When I started with Linux I started with Ubuntu. So based on my experience I recomend you to start with Ubuntu.